# Whenever i select a value in a column it turns blue and i can't read

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I have a problem that whenever i select a value in a column table it turns blue, and when i write on it, it takes all the previous writing off. Like "Hello Person" when i select that value in a column it takes everything off. This only happens to a specific column, the other column doesn't? Im working on visual studio SQL

I'm working inside Microsoft visual studio 2015 and displayed my table's data and when i configure the value of the column which has nChar(50) it turns blue when selected. This problem occurred when i did a random key.I probably just need to find the key combination to restore back to no highlights. Thanks!

Comment: I need an answer as it is very annoying

Comment: Please provide additional information. When you say "column table", are you referring to a control on a form? If so, which control? Is this a Web Application, a WPF Application, a Winforms Application or something else? When you say "visual studio SQL" are you referring to SQL Server Management Studio? Are you referring to viewing/editing data in a table's edit view? If so, what's the data type of the column?

Comment: Edited the question, please answer @BobKaufman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the value was being shifted to the right, don't know how many times, making me think that the value would be deleted on the press. Unfortunately, the solution wasn't a good one, i had to drop the database. This problem could be resolved by figuring out how to not indent the value. Good luck on your search!